# Skip parsing certain tags

Tags: parsing, templates, freemarker

Is there a way to skip parsing certain tags for the entire application? E.g. there are a lot of `<pre>` tags throughout my templates and I want to skip all of them without boring insertion of `<#noparse>` tag in each place.

Comment: Why do you use `#noparse` around `pre` elements? Do you want to show FTL source code inside `pre` tags for some kind of documentation?

Comment: You're almost correct. Our templates include `${}` that is pretty common syntax and used not only by Freemarker..

Comment: A quite common syntax clash unfortunately. But why's that related to `pre`?

Comment: we have many code snippets in our templates and almost all those snippets have "interpolated expressions" that are not of Freemarker's ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad luck if you have a lot of `${}`-s in your templates that aren't FreeMarker interpolations. (This eventually will have to be addressed by FreeMarker with a syntactical option.) For escaping individual `${exp}`-s there are some hacks that are shorter than `<#noparse>${exp}</#noparse>`:

```
<#macro $>${'$'}{<#nested>}</#macro>
```

and then

```
<@$>exp</@>
```

or

```
${'$'}{exp}
```

It's also possible to post-process templates on the fly (i.e., when they are loaded), if you provide your own `TemplateLoader` implementation (see also `Configuration.setTemplateLoader`), which wraps the real `TemplateLoader` and filters the `Reader` it creates. Because at that level your are working with plain `Reader`-s, parsing is up to you, which is not that trivial to do properly though. With that it's even possible to replace `<pre>...</pre>` with `<#noparse><pre>...</pre></#noparse>`, though I think that such magic will be quite confusing for other developers. So if you go down the post-processing path, I would recommend using something like `<#pre>...</#pre>` (a fake FTL tag, but at least it's clear that something additional is happening here).

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your answer as a Freemarker's developer. We decided to resort to using a separate TemplateLoader

Comment: We are just considering a configuration option to use `{{exp}}` or `@{exp}` instead of the default `${exp}` (and `#{exp}`) BTW.